# CSS HTML issue - Toolbar extends too far

Tags: html, css

This is the code I am working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/BTYA7/

I can't work out why the toolbar (blue) is extending past the right side of the text box. There doesnt seem to be any padding or margin a miss.

I applied it in blue and pink to help show it:

```
.uEditorToolbar {background-color: blue;}
```

Can anyone give some guidance please?

Comment: `.uEditor .uEditorToolbar` has a 2px padding on the left.

Comment: EDIT: Fixed, thank you! Please add a short answer and ill accept.

Comment: approve jdwire's answer, its just the same with more details ;)
and you will be helping a noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The uEditorToolbar has two extra pixels of padding. `width:100%` sets the width not including padding. If need the padding, you can remove the `width:100%`, and the blue bar doesn't extend too far.

Is that what you need, or am I missing something.

Comment: You are right, as i said in my comment, there is a 2px padding,
Removing it fixes the problem (without removing the `width:100%`)

Answer (score 1):

The default layout style as specified by the CSS standard means that the width and height properties are measured including only the content, but not the border, margin, or padding. So the combination of `width:100%` and `padding: 0 0 0 2px;` is pushing the content out by 2px.

The default display for `<ul>` is block so the `width:100%` is probably unnecessary anyway.

If you remove the `width:100%` or the `padding-left` will fix the problem.

Alternatively, the CSS3 [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) property can be used to correct the layout by using `box-sizing: border-box;` (if all browsers you are targeting [support the property](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-box)).

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a 2px padding. If I remove the padding then it looks ok.

```
.uEditor .uEditorToolbar
{
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BTYA7/5/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width:100%; padding: 2px;` from the `.uEditor .uEditorToolbar` CSS class. It will work.